Estimated payoff for vanilla option always returns 0 in Quantlib
Using QL.NET to get estimated option payoff but always get 0 for either European or American style options. Any suggestion what's wrong?
    double GetOptionEstimate()
    {
      var riskFreeRate = 0.05;
      var dividendYield = 0.00;
      var calendar = new TARGET();
      var dayCounter = new Actual365Fixed();
      var settlementDate = DateTime.Parse("8/14/2024 9:31:09 AM");
      var expirationDate = DateTime.Parse("8/14/2024 4:00:00 PM");
      var volatility = 29.226;
      var optionType = Option.Type.Put;
      var strike = 543;
      var currentPrice = 543.19;

      Settings.setEvaluationDate(settlementDate);

      var basis = new Handle<Quote>(new SimpleQuote(currentPrice));

      var flatTermStructure = new Handle<YieldTermStructure>(new FlatForward(settlementDate, riskFreeRate, dayCounter));
      var flatDividendTS = new Handle<YieldTermStructure>(new FlatForward(settlementDate, dividendYield, dayCounter));
      var flatVolTS = new Handle<BlackVolTermStructure>(new BlackConstantVol(settlementDate, calendar, volatility, dayCounter));
      var payoff = new PlainVanillaPayoff(optionType, strike);
      var bsmProcess = new BlackScholesMertonProcess(basis, flatDividendTS, flatTermStructure, flatVolTS);

      var europeanExercise = new EuropeanExercise(expirationDate);
      var americanExercise = new AmericanExercise(settlementDate, expirationDate);
      var europeanOption = new VanillaOption(payoff, europeanExercise);
      var americanOption = new VanillaOption(payoff, americanExercise);

      europeanOption.setPricingEngine(new AnalyticEuropeanEngine(bsmProcess));
      americanOption.setPricingEngine(new BaroneAdesiWhaleyApproximationEngine(bsmProcess));

      return americanOption.NPV();
    }

